# How to append a row of a CSV as a string (and not individual lists) to a list

Tags: python, python-3.x

I have a .csv file with one column (approx 5k rows). I want to convert all this into a list that looks like this:

```
key_list = ['key_1','key_2','key_3'...]
```

The 'key_1', 'key_2' etc are individual rows within my csv file.

To do this, I am using the csv module. My code does:

```
import csv

key_list = []

with open('key_list.csv','r') as file:
    reader = csv.reader(file, delimiter = ',')

    for row in reader:
        key_list.append(row)
```

However this creates the following output when I go to `print(key_list)`:

```
[['key_1'],['key_2']]
```

When I then go to use this in my code, by looping through the list, I am trying to save `key_list[0] = 'key_1'` as a string, but my code is outputting `['key_1']` as a list and failing.

What do I need to change so I can get a list that looks like:

```
key_list = ['key_1','key_2','key_3'...]
```

Thank you

Comment: `key_list.append(row[0])`…

Comment: Great, this worked. Thank you. Out of curiosity, what does adding the index in the append do differently vs what I was doing?

Comment: you only have one entry for each line in the csv?

Comment: The CSV reader always gives you a *row*, even if there's only one column in that row. If you only want to append one value from the row (the only value there is), well, then you'll need to *append only one value* with `row[0]`, instead of the entire row with `row`.

Comment: @deceze totally agree with you. I was just wondering how that csv would look like.

Answer (score 0):

You can unpack the first column from the row:

```
key_list = [key for key, in reader]
```

Answer (score 0):

You can also do in one line with map:

```
import csv
key_list = list(map(lambda row: row[0], csv.reader(open('key_list.csv'))))
print(key_list)
```

Or list comprehension:

```
import csv
key_list = [row[0] for row in csv.reader(open('key_list.csv'))]
print(key_list)
```

Answer (score -1):

When you read the CSV file, each row is going to be treated as a list. so changing each list to a string will give you the key_list = ['key_1','key_2','key_3'...] as key_1, key_2, ... as a string.
Try this one,

```
import csv

key_list = []

with open('snakes_count_10.csv','r') as file:
    reader = csv.reader(file, delimiter = ',')

    for row in reader:
        key_list.append(', '.join(row))

print(key_list)
```

Comment: I think this could be a solution, but I think his problem is that he only have one column in the csv